# Turning returned string into dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, urllib2

I'm working on a simple python script. It uses urllib to read from a web page and turn it into a dictionary. The way the webserver outputs is a dictionary because it uses JSON. Here is what I have:

```
import urllib2
d = 'http://www.somewebserver.com/tools/dictionary.php?string=hello'
r = urllib2.urlopen(d)
data = r.read()
r.close()
dictionary = dict(data)
print dictionary
```

Only problem is when I run it I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get.py", line 6, in getstring()
    dictionary = dict(data)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 20; 2 is required
```

How can I succesfully turn this into a dictionary?

Answer (score 6):

```
import json
dictionary = json.loads(data)
```

Or to save some steps you can pass your file object `r` to `json.load`:

```
dictionary = json.load(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the JSON routines in the [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) module to turn it into Python objects.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to [de-marshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29) your json data into a dictionary.

```
import json
dictionary = json.loads(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.python.org/library/json.html

```
import json

json.loads('["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]')

[u'foo', {u'bar': [u'baz', None, 1.0, 2]}]
```